# make list of const and its value using for loop js

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, eval

I want to generate these line of codes by using for loop

```
const clientAppProcessFlowIds = (listItem.clientAppProcessFlowId===null)?listItem.clientAppProcessFlowId='empty':String(listItem.clientAppProcessFlowId).toLowerCase();
const clientAppRoleIds = (listItem.clientAppRoleId ===null)?listItem.clientAppRoleId='empty':String(listItem.clientAppRoleId).toLowerCase()
const clientAppUserIds = (listItem.clientAppUserId ===null)?listItem.clientAppUserId='empty':String(listItem.clientAppUserId).toLowerCase()
const isApprovers = (listItem.isApprover ===null)?listItem.isApprover='empty':String(listItem.isApprover).toLowerCase()
const isInCharges = (listItem.isInCharge ===null)?listItem.isInCharge='empty':String(listItem.isInCharge).toLowerCase()
const isReferers = (listItem.isReferer ===null)?listItem.isReferer='empty':String(listItem.isReferer).toLowerCase()
const prioritys = (listItem.priority ===null)?listItem.priority='empty':String(listItem.priority).toLowerCase()
const actives = (listItem.active ===null)?listItem.active='empty':String(listItem.active).toLowerCase()
const createdAts = (listItem.createdAt ===null)?listItem.createdAt='empty':String(listItem.createdAt).toLowerCase()
const isDeleteds = (listItem.isDeleted ===null)?listItem.isDeleted='empty':String(listItem.isDeleted).toLowerCase()
const clientAppProcessFlows = (listItem.clientAppProcessFlow ===null)?listItem.clientAppProcessFlow='empty':String(listItem.clientAppProcessFlow).toLowerCase()
```

argList contain :

```
{
  id: '',
  clientAppProcessFlowId: '',
  clientAppRoleId: '',
  clientAppUserId: '',
  isApprover: '',
  isInCharge: '',
  isReferer: '',
  priority: '',
  active: '',
  createdAt: '',
  isDeleted: '',
  clientAppProcessFlow: '',
}
```

and `listItem` contain objects like :

```
{
  "id": 94,
  "clientAppProcessFlowId": 6,
  "clientAppRoleId": 542,
  "clientAppUserId": 452,
  "isApprover": true,
  "isInCharge": true,
  "isReferer": false,
  "priority": 99999999,
  "active": true,
  "createdAt": "2023-06-25T13:36:23.69",
  "isDeleted": false,
  "clientAppProcessFlow": null
}
```

I tried for like :

```
for(let arg in this.arguments){
    eval('const ' + arg+'s'  + '= ' + (listItem.arg===null)?listItem.arg='"empty"':String(listItem.arg).toLowerCase() + ';')
}
```

but it didn't work and its return me the last variable value

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Why not just use the object you have? If you want null values to be `'empty'` instead just map over the object and input those instead.

Comment: this code is in component ,argList and listItem can be different in content , so I need to do this dynamically

Comment: You need to put quotes around the result of `String(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out following snippet. It does what you want to do.

```js
const arguments = {
  id: '',
  clientAppProcessFlowId: '',
  clientAppRoleId: '',
  clientAppUserId: '',
  isApprover: '',
  isInCharge: '',
  isReferer: '',
  priority: '',
  active: '',
  createdAt: '',
  isDeleted: '',
  clientAppProcessFlow: '',
}

const listItem = {
  "id": 94,
  "clientAppProcessFlowId": 6,
  "clientAppRoleId": 542,
  "clientAppUserId": 452,
  "isApprover": true,
  "isInCharge": true,
  "isReferer": false,
  "priority": 99999999,
  "active": true,
  "createdAt": "2023-06-25T13:36:23.69",
  "isDeleted": false,
  "clientAppProcessFlow": null
}

for (let arg in arguments) {
  const stmt = 'var ' + arg + 's' + ' = "' + (listItem[arg] === null ? 'empty' : String(listItem[arg]).toLowerCase()) + '";'
  eval?.(stmt);
}
console.log({
  ids,
  clientAppProcessFlowIds,
  clientAppRoleIds
});
```

Comment: I'm soooo tanksful, it works